# Spring Boot @Autowired custom application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

i am trying to get my custon application.properties fields working within a kotlin spring boot application.

My Current Setup:

ApplicationProperties.kt:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("mt")
class ApplicationProperties {

    var initDatabase: Boolean? = null
    val kafka = Kafka()

    class Kafka {
        lateinit var host: String
        lateinit var port: String
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
mt.kafka.host=localhost
mt.kafka.port=9092
mt.init-database=true
```

And a class where i want to use my application:
InitApp.kt

```
@Component
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationProperties::class)
class InitApp {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var conf: ApplicationProperties

    @Bean
    fun createKafkaConsumer() {
        log.info("${conf.kafka.host}")
    }
}
```

Sadly this doesn't work because i get a:

```
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property conf has not been initialized
```

I followed this "guide" [Bootiful Kotlin by Sébastien Deleuze and Josh Long @ Spring I/O 2018](https://youtu.be/btNIey_2Zdw?t=1580) and i am using these versions:

```
    kotlinVersion = '1.2.51'
    springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
```

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` is in my build.gradle, but this should not mess with the `@Autowired` since, as far as i understood, it is for autocompletion in my application.properties.

## Update 1:

I had a look at: [Building web applications with Spring Boot and Kotlin](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/) and added the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` at Application level. This didn't work either

## Update  2:

Full stacktrace:

```
2018-10-10 16:17:53.058 ERROR 23619 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'producerFactory' defined in class path resource [de/mikatiming/de/test/InitApp.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory]: Factory method 'producerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property applicationProperties has not been initialized
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at de.mikatiming.de.test.TestApplicationKt.main(TestApplication.kt:15) [main/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory]: Factory method 'producerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property applicationProperties has not been initialized
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property applicationProperties has not been initialized
at de.mikatiming.de.test.InitApp.getApplicationProperties(InitApp.kt:36) ~[main/:na]
at de.mikatiming.de.test.InitApp.producerFactory(InitApp.kt:58) ~[main/:na]
at de.mikatiming.de.test.InitApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c3b698bb.CGLIB$producerFactory$10(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
at de.mikatiming.de.test.InitApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c3b698bb$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b315799f.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at de.mikatiming.de.test.InitApp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c3b698bb.producerFactory(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
... 24 common frames omitted
```

## Update 3:

I just found out that when i remove a specific bean from my InitApp:

```
@Bean
fun placeHolderConfigurer(): PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer {
    return PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
}
```

i get an other error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'de.mikatiming.messageengine.configuration.ApplicationProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

So it looks like it is an issue with this bean!

Comment: Wait a second...do you have this in your gradle config? `"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"`

Comment: yes i do, with the kapt plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working:

### Annotations

```
@Service
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableTransactionManagement
class AppConfig {
```

ApplicationProperties:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("mt")
class ApplicationProperties {
```

ApplicationClass:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationProperties::class)
abstract class MessageengineApplication
```

### Beans

i needed to remove the following Bean from AppConfig:

```
@Bean
fun placeHolderConfigurer(): PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer {
    return PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
}
```

Comment: Why is `@Service` and `@Configuration` in one place? This does not make sense to me

Answer (score 0):

This is ought to work:

```
@Component
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationProperties::class)
class InitApp {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var conf: ApplicationProperties

    // ...
}

@ConfigurationProperties("mt")
class ApplicationProperties {

    var initDatabase: Boolean? = null
    val kafka = Kafka()

    class Kafka {
        lateinit var host: String
        lateinit var port: String
    }
}
```

**Note that** you need to put `@Configuration` on `InitApp`, not on `ApplicationProperties`.

I also have these in my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

depencencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    compileOnly "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports { mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}") }
}
```

You need the `"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"` dependency in place in order for this whole thing to work.

Comment: Can you show us the full stack trace? I tried the code above in a project and it worked.

Comment: yep, i just added it to the main post.
I also created a clean project with just this setup, and it doesn't work. Could you provide me your project?

Answer (score -1):

`@EnableConfigurationProperties` is usually put on classes marked with `@Configuration` annotation.

In the code snippet `class InitApp` should be marked as a `@Configuration` and then you can (I don't know Kotlin, so I'll provide a java equivalent):

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationProperties.class)
public class InitApp {


  @Bean
  public <<BeanThatYouNeed>> kafkaConsumer(ApplicationProperties props) {
      log.info(props.getKafka().getHost());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this fast! 
Tried it, sadly it doesn't change anything. As of "https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/" @EnableConfigurationProperties should be put on Application level, tried this also doesn't chang anything

Answer (score -1):

you dont need those `@Configuration, @ConfigurationProperties("mt")` in the header of `class ApplicationProperties`
you can use @Value annotation to directly get the props from application.properties file

`

```
@Component
@EnableTransactionManagement
class InitApp {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var conf: ApplicationProperties
    @Bean
    fun createKafkaConsumer(@Value("${mt.kafka.host}") String host, 
                               @Value("${mt.kafka.host}") String port) {
        //you have host, port now
    }
}
```

`